# How to merge a SoapUI (free) project into a ReadyAPI (soapui pro) project?

Tags: merge, soapui

I'm currently working on a ReadyAPI project with a collegue. Our projects have the same resources (same swagger has been used) and we are developing different testSuites.

We have both a testSuite with the basic resources tested unitary and our own testSuites that refer to this testSuite's testCases.

example.

TSuite_common/TCase1 : request1

TSuite_my_Collegue/TCase1 : run TSuite_common/TCase 1 + some processing

TSuite_my_testSuite/TCase1 : run TSuite_common/TCase 1 + some other processing

We want to merge projects in order to have all the testSuites but when I export/import his testSuites, the references to resources are lost, ie. references to TSuite_common/TCase1, altough I have the exact same TSuite_common/TCase1 in my project !

It is not possible to resolve all the links by hand as there are too many of them, is there a particular option that I have to set to do the merge properly ?

Do I have to use groovy scripting ?

thanks in advance

Alexandre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally I found a way to proceed. 
In SOAPUI, a 'Run test case step' implies the creation of a reference linked based on the distant test case's uid. 
As the TSuite_common/TCase's uid is not the same in my project (destination) and in my colleague's project (source), I had to build a script to play on the exported source/testSuite
This script :
- gets the referenced test case's name from its uid (in the source/TSuite_common)
- gets the corresponding uid from the testcase's name in the destination/TSuite_common (which contains the same APIs as in the source)
- replace the referenced test case's uid with the uid just found
- import the testSuite in myProject
There is no unresolved links

Note that it's finally fairly easy as the testSuites imported have a different name from mine. 
Next step : merge an existing testSuite from another project (!)